# Abrir o Navegador Apertando um botão na Activity

Tags: java, android

Como abrir um site apertando um botão na activity?

Comment: Abrir onde? Numa WebView ou num browser instalado no dispositivo Android?

Comment: Abrir no browser, Chrome ou Firefox!